# how to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dynamic Disk?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

Guy actually i am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 using a USB but while installation the option **along side Windows** is missing. I heard that if we have a dynamic Disk, Ubuntu will not give the option *along side windows*.

So please help me out in installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my system.

My system configuration:

OS: Windows 7,
Intel i3 processor,
4 GB RAM,
1TB Hard Disk.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the manual installation. Select the partition on which you want to install Ubuntu, Create partition as `ext4` and mount point should be : `/`.

Be careful when choosing the partition, you don't want to wipe your Windows install ! After everything is finished whenever you reboot, GRUB should appear and let you choose on which OS to boot.

P.S.: You can add a swap as well if you need to. and don't forget to backup before doing the install !

Comment: hey @sekh i am new to ubuntu basically, When i choose something else it has been showing my Hard Disk as a single unit with partitions missing. So basically thought it might be the issue with file format of my HDD

Comment: @abraham strange, since your filesystem should be ntfs. Anyway as I see a link helped so all should be good.